# Select files between two dates

Tags: batch-file, date

```
@echo off
forfiles /p "C:\Documents and Settings\Test\Downloads" /d +01/07/2011 /d -15/07/2011 /c "cmd /c echo @file"
pause
```

Hello,

I would like to select all files modified between 01/07/11 and 15/07/11 (French : jj/mm/aaaa or USA : dd/mm/yyyy). But the "/d" parameter can be used only one time. How can I do that ?

Thanks if you can help me. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an option for that particular command.  You could use the selection as input to a FOR loop.  Add another indention for each criteria you need.

```
FOR /F "delims=*" %%A IN ('forfiles /d -05/07/2011') DO (
    FOR /F "delims=*" %%B IN ('forfiles /m %%A /d +05/01/2011') DO (
        ECHO %%B
    )
)
```

Comment: It's working. What do I have to modify to not print the few "Error : No file found..." ?
And I have to launch this script in a 500.000+ files folder and it seems extremely slow. Can the second 'for' be replaced by a 'if' ? It would be more optimized I think.

Comment: "Extremely slow" may be the performance of your system, or it may mean "Not Optimized."  The best thing to do would be to use a programming language like Visual Basic or C# to create a compiled executable.  This would be very optimized.